# How to diagnose and fix an unkillable IE tab?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8

I've used Windows for years.  IE has generally been rock solid, though a bit slower than Firefox on Javascript-heavy webpages.

I now have a Dell laptop running Windows 7 Home Basic.  From time to time IE8 (the default, builtin version of IE) gets in a state where it becomes unkillable. If I type sometihng in the search box, like this:

[image]

...IE doesn't respond.  If I click the "close window" X, which normally results in a dialog box asking "Close all tabs?"... nothing happens.  If I try to close an individual tab, nothing happens.

How to diagnose this?

Have I got a bad BHO?

Anyone else seen this?

My current approach is to kill all IE windows from within Task Manager, then restart.

Assistance or hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hate to say it, but if one chooses to use beta software, such hiccups are to be expected. Perhaps try to report a bug with Microsoft? Kill the task and send the crash report?

Funny thing is, I've experienced the exact problem you describe too, but with Firefox 4 Beta 7. In my case Flash was the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I just checked and I was mistaken when I tagged the question with IE9.  It is actually IE8.  I am not using the beta IE9 software.  I will check on Flash, though.

Comment: I see. If Internet Explorer also has a *Safe mode* option, have you tried that? It may at least help you diagnose whether the problem lies with Internet Explorer or one of its plugins.